# C# Proxy/IP Spoofing HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, http-proxy

I have searched for similar questions and yet not found any answer..
Many times in making HttpWebRequests..the website blocks the IP address..
Could any one go over the IP Spoofing / Proxy method in .NET Web Requests..

If IP address could not be changed..then a method to integrate Proxy in web requests..Would I need a Proxy Server for that? I'm a noob...so don't really know what to do...

In the code samples..that I have found...People usually do this thing..
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("192.168.1.200", 8080);

what do these two parameters signify? bcz I get ""Unable to connect to remote server""

EDIT::
How would I implement SOCKS or any other proxy..Any library that can be used..??

Comment: You *actually* need a HTTP proxy to proxy through, so where you see `192.168.1.200:8080` they probably have a proxy running on that IP and port.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: What @Lloyd said. You can't just invent random proxy settings to use. It's not just a "thing" you write into a line or 2 of code. Install one, use it's correct address, then try this method again. You are `Unable to connect to the remote server` because the address you're using doesn't exist...

Answer (score 2):

First off, use [System.Net.WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) please...

Example for your problem:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
// Want a proxy?
wc.Proxy = new WebProxy("*proxy-host*", *proxy-port(int)*);
var downloadedContent = wc.DownloadString("url");
```

Make sure the proxy is online and is a **HTTP Proxy**, not a HTTPS and not a SOCKS Proxy and you can connect to it!
For a list of proxies look here: [HideMyAss](http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/)

WebProxy Constructor Reference: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xfsh37cx(v=vs.110).aspx)